# IEEEtran class: how to achieve "small caps" font effect?

Tags: ieeetran, small-caps

In the IEEEtran class, how can I achieve the "small caps" font effect used for e.g. stating the names of IEEE societies and publications, and the section titles (see example below)?

Thanks and regards, Jorge.

P.S. The class can be found [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls).

**Example font I'd like to achieve:**
[image]

**Example code:**

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\section{This is a dummy section}
% Some sample text I'd like to put in small-caps font:
How to, for example, put \emph{this text} in the same font as the section title?

\end{document}
```

**Output of example code:**
[image]

Comment: `\textsc{foo}` should do it.

Comment: Thanks moewe, that does the trick indeed! Regards, Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all you need is `\textsc{}` for this, as moewe pointed out.

**Solution:**

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a dummy section}

% Some sample text I'd like to put in small-caps font:
%How to, for example, put \emph{This Text} in the same font as the section title?
How to, for example, put \textsc{This Text} in the same font as the section title?

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]